# How do embed an inline-iframe in the newsfeed like soundcloud does?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I feel like this question gets asked multiple times but no one seems to have an answer.

It appears Facebook is whitelisting the soundcloud app and replacing the og:video ("type": "application/x-shockwave-flash") tag information with a different html5 inline experience.

How does someone get this approved for their own domain? Is there a form to fill out? Is there someone to talk to?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Soundcloud is testing embedding HTML5. We are current not accepting more people to test it. So you just have to wait.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you know when apps can apply to have their apps featured inline in the newsfeed? I can't seem to find anything about this on the internet. Any answer is much appreciated!